# Is there a symbol for assigning an equation to a letter

Tags: proof-writing, notation, systems-of-equations

When solving simultaneous equations, such as:$$3x+5y=2$$$$x+6y=14$$You will multiply one by a scalar to eliminate a variable:$$A: 3x+5y=2$$$$B: x+6y=14$$$$A-3B:-13y=-40$$ etc...

When I gave each equation a letter, $A$ and $B$, is there a conventional symbol to use for that, or is a colon fine?

Thanks :)

Comment: The colon is ok. Parenthesis can be used too, such as $(A)\ 3x+5y=2$.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people assign (i), (ii), or $(*),(**)$ etc. to label equations, and then say by doing $(ii)-(i)$ etc., you get $(iii)$ or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Because the study of linear systems inexorably leads to the study of matrices, I prefer to use the notation $R_i$ for the $i^\text{th}$-row of a linear system when I teach linear algebra/systems.

In your example, I would write $R_1 - 3R_2$.

This becomes especially useful when the number of rows is greater than three.